# How to get single/first image for phrase(track and album)

Tags: image

Google api or samting else do get first image for passphrase.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the hope you won't build another image scraping tool to attempt to game Google Images:

Take a look at the [Google WebSearch API](http://code.google.com/apis/websearch/docs/) (and its [Terms of Service](http://code.google.com/apis/websearch/terms.html)). The documentation should get you started with how to use the API and will tell you what URLs to query and how.
By default, you would query https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q=Google, mind the 'web' word in the path.

To query for images, you would change that word to 'images', like this:  https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?v=1.0&q=Google

You parse the results, which is simple JSON, and there you go, you have the first image in the Images results.

Comment: and how to limit result to single image

Comment: You will need to parse the results (the JSON). This will result in an object and the first image result will be in object[0]

Comment: Unfortunately, the google image search API is deprecated.